# Применение различных циклов for для массива, в чем разница?

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

---

Доброго времени суток! Решая задачки по JS на CodeWars.com наткнулся на вопрос связанный с циклом for для массива. 
Суть задачи, написать функцию которая преобразует массив с числами [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], в формат "(123) 456-7890".

В первом случае, когда используем цикл for(let i = 0; i < arr.length, i++), то получаем результат тот что нужен. Уже во втором случае, когда используем цикл for(let item of arr) я получаю не преобразованный формат. Помогите разобраться, почему во втором случае в теле цикла for не перезаписываются значения?!

```js
let phoneNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function createPhoneNumber1(numb){
    let phoneNumberInType = "(***) ***-****".split("");
    let count = 0;

    for(let i=0; i < phoneNumberInType.length; i++) {
        if(phoneNumberInType[i] == "*") {
            phoneNumberInType[i] = numb[count++] ;
        }
    }

    return phoneNumberInType.join(''); 
}

console.log(createPhoneNumber1(phoneNumber)); // Получаем строку "(123) 456-7890"

function createPhoneNumber2(numb){
    let phoneNumberInType = "(***) ***-****".split("");
    let count = 0;

    for(let item of phoneNumberInType) {
        if(item == "*") {
            item = numb[count++];
        }
    }

    return phoneNumberInType.join(''); 
}

console.log(createPhoneNumber2(phoneNumber)); // Получаем строку "(***) ***-****"
```

Comment: Потому что примитивные типы в js `number, string, null, undefined, boolean, bigInt` копируются по значению. Так что, когда вы проходитесь циклом for..of, у вас каждый раз создается НОВАЯ КОПИЯ каждого из обьектов массива. Если бы у вас был массив обьектов, то вы бы могли бы их менять, получив доступ к свойствам через точечную нотацию

Comment: sidenote: вариант без цикла `"(***) ***-****".replace(/\*/g, (it => () => it.next().value)(phoneNumber[Symbol.iterator]()))`

Comment: P.s. `function createPhoneNumber(numb) { let i = 0; return "(***) ***-****".replace(/\*/g, _ => numb[i++]); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let phoneNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function createPhoneNumber2(numb){
    let phoneNumberInType = "(***) ***-****".split("");
    let count = 0;
    let index = 0; // введем дополнительную переменную, чтобы показать, что мы создаем новую переменную при каждой итерации.

    for(let item of phoneNumberInType) { // тут при каждой итерации цикла создается новая переменная item, которая по значению равна очередному значению в массиве.
        if(item == "*") {
            item = numb[count++]; // тут вы меняете не элемент массива, а новенькую переменную, которая была создана при очередной итерации.
            
            console.log(`item: ${item}, phoneNumberInType[${index}]: ${phoneNumberInType[index]}`) // чтобы показать, что элементы phoneNumberInType остаются не тронуты
        }
        
        index++; // при каждей итерации меняем индекс (аналог i в for)
    }

    return phoneNumberInType.join(''); 
}

console.log(createPhoneNumber2(phoneNumber)); // Получаем строку "(***) ***-****"
```

```js
let friends = [{name: 'Vlad'}, {name: 'Victor'}, {name: 'Igor'}];

for (let friend of friends) { // Обьекты копируются по ссылке, по-этому вы можете изменять их в цикле for..of. (Новый обьект не создается).
  friend.name = 'Tolik'; 
}

console.log(friends); // Кажется в друзьях остались одни Толики.
```

```js
let friends = [{name: 'Vlad'}, {name: 'Victor'}, {name: 'Igor'}];

for (let friend of friends) { 
  friend = {name: 'Tolik'}; // В данном случае создается новый обьект, а ссылка на него переприсваивается переменной, которая раньше ссылалась на обьет в массиве. При этом сам обьект, находящийся в массиве никак не задет. 
}

console.log(friends); // Ничего не изменилось
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут тип цикла не важен. Во втором варианте вы изменяете значение переменной, но не трогаете массив. Точно также массив не изменится если сделать вот так:

```
let item = phoneNumberInType[0]
item = null  //здесь присвоение любого значения не изменяет массив
```

Если же очень хочется решить эту задачу с for ... of , то можно сделать так:

```
function createPhoneNumber2(numb){
    let phoneNumberInType = "(***) ***-****".split("");
    let count = 0;

    for(let [key, item] of phoneNumberInType.entries()) {
        if(item == "*") {
            phoneNumberInType[key] = numb[count++];
        }
    }

    return phoneNumberInType.join(''); 
}
```

Нужно изменять значение в самом массиве, для этого нужно знать индекс. Этот тип цикла не предполагает индексов, но мы можем сами его создать с помощью метода entries.